# How do I configure a bank account?

Tags: purchase-price

I just installed the Magento and I am learning to use it. I have a question, let's assume the user complete an order and paid it using a credit card. Where does the money go? how/when will I be able to transfer it to my own bank account?

Comment: You sign up with a credit card processor that has produced a Magento module that contacts their gateway and authorizes the credit card for charge. It then gets deposited directly into your bank account you provide to them. There are other legacy methods that people attempt to use, until they get hacked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit card processing isn't quite magic. Before you can accept credit card payments, you are going to have to find a credit card processor, apply and get approved for a business account, and then set up the gateway within Magento to connect to your new account.

That's how the money gets from customers to you: You link Magento to your payment gateway account, and then when customers enter their credit card details, Magento sends that info to that payment gateway. The payment gateway takes their money, and their order goes into Magento as successful. Then you can transfer the funds from your payment gateway to your actual bank account (usually after a few week delay).

There are many payment gateways/credit card processors you can choose from. They each have different fees and policies.

- [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/accept-payments-online) is very well integrated into Magento, so it's a solid choice. PayPal Express lets customers use their own PayPal accounts to pay. Safe and easy.
- [Authorize.Net](http://www.authorize.net/) is also supported by Magento out-of-box, along with any payment processor that supports 'Authorize.Net emulation' (many do).

Comment: Thanks! I thought after installed the magneto I was ready to process credit cards from costumers I didn't think the card processor. I thought this was like Paypal. Can I use PayPal *as* my credit card processor in the magneto? Is this possible? if so, can point me to a direction to start implemting it?

Comment: @Jack, yes, that is possible. I gave a link above where you can get more info and sign up. When that's done, see here on how to add it to Magento: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/magento-shopping-cart

Comment: I've already a PayPal account, the 2th is broke to me I get a 404 error (maybe because I'm from a different country)? but I got the point, it's a magneto extension, right?

Comment: You don't need an extension, it's built in. You just need to go into Magento settings and set it up. Admin > System > Configuration > Payment Methods > PayPal